# Ipad GoodNotes 5 Icon in toolbar: what is it used for?

Tags: user-interface, ipad

There is the following icon in goodnotes 5. i searched the entire help but was not able to find its usage. Please  let me know if you know what this icon is used for. Doesn't seem to do anything.

[image: GoodNotes 5 icon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presenter icon (the one with the Bluetooth symbol on the left top) is used during presentations. If you are planning to share the screen of your iPad then you can use this to point out various elements on your drawing screen.

I hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

just found out, It is used during presentation screen sharing